# How to create multiple table with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a dropdown list (which holds numbers from 0 to 50) and html table. I want that when user select a value from list, code copy/create the tables to the amount of selected value.

Example: user picked 10. page should show me 10 same tables.

Can someone provide any hint?

Comment: I realise you may be new to this, but what have you started? Where are you stuck? What have you tried?

Comment: So, you found answer. Please accept one of answers below or if you think there is no good answer then post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming jQuery, here is a *very basic example.* It probably won't fit your needs so just use it to help you get started:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="dropDownOption">1</a>
<a href="#" class="dropDownOption">2</a>
<a href="#" class="dropDownOption">3</a>
<a href="#" class="dropDownOption">4</a>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('.dropDownOption').click(function() {
    var numberTables = parseInt($(this).html()),
        tableHTML = "<table class='table'><tr><td>Foo</td><td>Bar</td><tr><td>Spam</td><td>Ham</td></tr></table>";
    for (var i = 0; i < numberTables; i++) {
        $('body').append(tableHTML);
    }
});​
```

**JSFiddle:** 
 http://jsfiddle.net/TnTPf/2/

Answer (score 0):

### JQuery is one easy way to do this

My hint for you: find out what `$('#mytable').clone();` does.

#### Bonus hint:

`for (i=0; i<=50; i++) { /* clone here */ }`

Comment: sorry for late response but thanks for your answer. after i posted this message i figured out and found the solution. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function getTable(){
        var num = document.getElementById("txtnum").value;
        var table = "";
        for(i=0; i<13; i++ ){
        table += num + "x" + i + "=" + num*i + "<br>"; 

     }
      document.getElementById("mulTable").innerHTML = table;
 }


</script>
```

Comment: Please provide explanation with your code about what differ from the author's code and what was the problem in first place